# extract info from a column for a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which has data from Active Directory. It has 3 columns; namely: Machine Name, DistinguishedName and ObjectPath. For Example:

```
a. Machine Name: WKS123BBB
b. Distinguished Name: CN=WKS123BBB,OU=Workstations,OU=GB,OU=Countries,DC=A,DC=B,DC=C,DC=com
c. ObjectPath: LDAP://a.b.c.com,CN=WKS123BBB,OU=Workstations,OU=GB,OU=Countries,DC=A,DC=B,DC=C,DC=com
```

Below the domain we have Countries OU, below this OU we have Country Code (US), below Country code we have 3 OU's for Workstations. There are 18 Countries.

I am trying to create a view in SQL SERVER with the below column:

```
a. MachineName
b. OU
c. CountryCode
```

Note: There are 3 OU's below the Country code: Workstations, Workstations_Indus and WorkstationsDisabled

Can someone please help how to extract the Country Code and OU from Distinguished Name column. For example it should be like:

```
a. MachineName = WKS123BBB
b. OU = Workstations/Workstations_Indus/WorkstationsDisabled
c. CountryCode = GB
```

from  `CN=WKS123BBB,OU=Workstations,OU=GB,OU=Countries,DC=A,DC=B,DC=C,DC=com`

Thanks in advance

Comment: An idea would be to create a CLR assembly that called RegEx.Find method in .NET framework.

Comment: Thanks, I want to do this using a SQL Query. May be use an in-built function, not sure....

Comment: @Rajiv See this link.. may it will help to you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql   you can use PATINDEX to split by "," and then find "OU" from the current substring..

Comment: Is distinguished name always in the same format? - Perhaps you could run a SELECT TOP 5 DistinguishedName FROM [yourtable] to get us some more test data.

Comment: @Mack: Yes, its the format how Active Directory stores.

Comment: For splitting, you can use this sample: http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/best-split-function-tsql-delimited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a bit horrible but works. The input string has to have `CN=XXX,` and then two times `OU=XXX,` for it to work.

This should work ok in a view as it uses only deterministic `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` functions.

```
declare @s as varchar(200) = 'CN=WKS123BBB,OU=Workstations,OU=GB,OU=Countries,DC=A,DC=B,DC=C,DC=com'

select SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX('CN=', @s, 1) + 3, CHARINDEX(',', @s, CHARINDEX('CN=', @s, 1) + 2) - 4) as MachineName,
    SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX(',OU=', @s, 1) + 4, CHARINDEX(',', @s, CHARINDEX(',OU=', @s, 1) + 1) - CHARINDEX(',OU=', @s, 1) - 4) as OU,
    SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX(',OU=', @s, CHARINDEX(',OU=', @s, 1) + 1) + 4, CHARINDEX(',', @s, CHARINDEX(',OU=', @s, CHARINDEX(',OU=', @s, 1) + 1) + 1) -CHARINDEX(',OU=', @s, CHARINDEX(',OU=', @s, 1) + 1) - 4) as CountryCode
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Unfortunately I came to know that are 2 more OU's under Country code, which make 3 in total which are static across all Countries. Workstations, Workstations_Indus and WorkstationsDisabled. Could you please help for this too.... Thanks a lot

Comment: Rather than asking @Szymon to it all for you, wouldn't it be better fo you to work through the above example and learn how to do it yourself.

Comment: @Rajiv It will work for 2 more parts but will become rather horrible. See the pattern, because of the repeating `OU=`, there has to be `charindex` within `charindex`. But you can give our a go.

Comment: @Syzmon: Thank you very much for your advice. It really helped me in learning something new. Thanks :)